Find tight upper bound on $p$ such that an asymptotic inequality holds
I am dealing with the following question but I am not 100% sure whether my deduction is correct. Could someone help me to double check? I will highlight the parts that I'm unsure about.
The question is
Find tight upper bound of $p\in(0,1/2)$ such that
$$\pi+\frac{2\pi}{\delta}(1+3\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{1}{p}-2})\prec e^{\frac{n^2/4-\log\binom{n}{n/2}}{n}}$$
where $\delta\in(0,1)$ is a constant.
Note that $\prec$ denotes asymptotically smaller than.
My solution
Step 1. Clearly, when $p$ tends to $1/2$ (below $1/2$), the left hand side tends to $+\infty$. Thus, in order to guarantee the above asympstotic inequality holds, it is equivalent to guarantee that:
the speed of $p$ tends to $1/2$ is slower than the speed of right-hand side tends to $+\infty$.
Thus we start to calculate the speed of RHS as follows.
Step 2.
Since $\frac{n^2/4-\log\binom{n}{n/2}}{n}\sim \frac{n^2/4-\log 2^n+\log\sqrt{\frac{n\pi}{2}}}{n}$ where I used the formula $\binom{2n}{n}\sim\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{n\pi}}$ (not sure I should use this, or should I use the first inequality $\binom{n}{k}\leq \frac{n^k}{k!}$ in the section "Bounds and asymptotic formulas" in wiki?)
Step 3. Then, it is $=\frac{n}{4}-\log 2+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\log(\frac{n}{2}\pi)}{n}$ which should $\sim \frac{n}{4}$ (Am I correct?)
Step 4. Then, I plug-in $e^{n/4}$ arriving
$$\pi+\frac{2\pi}{\delta}(1+3\frac{1}{1/p-2})\prec e^{n/4}$$
after deduction we have
$$p\prec \frac{1}{2}-\frac{3\pi}{\delta}\frac{1}{e^{n/4}-\pi+\pi/\delta}\sim \frac{1}{2}-O(e^{-n/4})$$
thus we write $$p\prec \frac{1}{2}-O(e^{-n/4})$$
Many thanks in advance!
